# T-SQL results per day for 1 year between time range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to return count on results per day between a time range that will overlap days.

So from 8 PM to 8 AM for every day that starts on M-F return a count for that time period. And do that for the entire year.

This is what I have, and I could do a simple and between if I only wanted on day but I'm not sure how to iterate through days especially when the start is on one day and the end on the next but skip the ones that Start on a Saturday or Sunday.

```
SELECT TOP (50)
    ClientVisit.visittype,
    ClientVisit.location_id,
    ClientVisit.visittype_id,
    Location.location_desc,
    Location.location_code,
    ClientVisit.timein,
    ClientVisit.timeout,
    ClientVisit.visit_dateday
FROM 
    ClientVisit
INNER JOIN 
    Location ON ClientVisit.location_id = Location.location_id
WHERE
    (ClientVisit.visittype Like '%Open Chart%'
     OR ClientVisit.visittype LIKE '%Diag%')
    AND (Location.location_code = 'Access-505'
         OR Location.location_code = 'Access-hosp')
    AND (ClientVisit.timein BETWEEN @param1 AND @param2)
```

Comment: Do you mind adding some sample data/schema/expected result? I would say its worth noting that with SQL, methods using a set based approached should be preferred over iteration.

Comment: I think you are doing too much of business logic in TSQL. Better to get the data and do the processing in the application layer.

Comment: Credible database!

Comment: Which day do the hours from midnight to 8am get associated with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering days of week and hours of the day is easy enough. Does this `group by` get at what you're trying to accomplish for the counts?

```
SELECT CAST(ClientVisit.timein AS DATE) AS DT, COUNT(*)
FROM ClientVisit INNER JOIN Location
    ON ClientVisit.location_id = Location.location_id
WHERE
        (ClientVisit.visittype Like '%Open Chart%' OR ClientVisit.visittype LIKE '%Diag%')
    AND (Location.location_code = 'Access-505' OR Location.location_code = 'Access-hosp')
    -- Use date params rather than datetime
    AND CAST(ClientVisit.timein AS DATE) BETWEEN @param1 AND @param2
    -- M-F assuming @@DATEFIRST is Sunday (7)
    AND DATEPART(weekday, ClientVisit.timein) BETWEEN 2 AND 6
    -- time of day. won't include the instant of 8:00:00am
    AND (   DATEPART(hour, ClientVisit.timein) BETWEEN 8 AND 23
        OR  DATEPART(hour, ClientVisit.timein) BETWEEN 0 AND 7)
GROUP BY CAST(ClientVisit.timein AS DATE);
```

If you need to treat the hours from 8PM to 8AM as a single shift then you can adjust the times prior to so that times after midnight are treated as part of the preceeding day:

```
WITH AdjustedVisit AS (
    SELECT *, DATEADD(hour, -8, timein) AS adjustedin FROM ClientVisit)
    -- Use date params rather than datetime
    WHERE CAST(timein AS DATE) BETWEEN @param1 AND @param2
)
SELECT CAST(v.adjustedin AS DATE) AS DT, COUNT(*)
FROM AdjustedVisit AS v INNER JOIN Location AS l
    ON v.location_id = l.location_id
WHERE
        (v.visittype Like '%Open Chart%' OR v.visittype LIKE '%Diag%')
    AND (l.location_code = 'Access-505' OR l.location_code = 'Access-hosp')
    -- M-F assuming @@DATEFIRST is Sunday (7)
    AND DATEPART(weekday, v.adjustedin) BETWEEN 2 AND 6
    -- time of day. won't include the instant of 8:00:00am
    AND DATEPART(hour, v.adjustedin) BETWEEN 12 AND 23
GROUP BY CAST(v.adjustedin AS DATE);
```

Comment: First, thank you. Next, this looks like it's good. To be clear the params are the start day and end day for the year as some times we calculate fiscal year and some times calendar year. Just running the query the numbers are looking correct but this looks like it's doing a count per client and not per day? Is that correct? If so I need to alter this for all clients on each day M-F for the entire period from param1 to param2. So it looks like I need to add in a sum and group by day of week, is that accurate?

Comment: I know this database and `visit_dateday` is the date serial number. You should use `ClientVisit.timein` or `ClientVisit.rev_timein`. You also need `DATEPART(hh, timein) BETWEEN 7 AND 19`

Comment: @Bryan, you are most likely seeing the serial number not client_id. They're 5 digits correct? Copy and paste on into excel and convert to date. :)

Comment: @Bryan I was just guessing since I have no familiarity with the database. The counts are intended to be per day but I just thought you had time and date components in separate columns.

Comment: @LarryB thanks, this is my first week on at this job so I'm still familiarizing myself with the database and fields.

Comment: @shawnt00  Thanks, I'll make Larry's suggested changes to your query and I hope that will work, right now I'm getting Saturday and Sunday days if I convert it in excel.

Comment: @Bryan I realized that you wanted 8pm to 8am and not the other way around. LarryB's suggestion made the same mistake. Hopefully I've sent you down the right path at least.

Comment: @Bryan, I've been there. I got over the learning curve by creating a spreadsheet of the tables and now I refer back to that spreadsheet. I actually created a Wiki as well but the spreadsheet was faster. If you have the BI piece and you are an admin you can query that information. Otherwise, I could email you that information.

Comment: @shawnt00 Thanks. One thing I did not mention is this is not a direct DB access so one restriction is the first line has to be a select statement so I cannot use the WITH part. I think I can rewrite your WITH into the select but   I keep running into limitations of this system so I'll have to try a few things.

Comment: Yeah, I just used the CTE as an example so I could avoid repeating the same expression over and over. It could just as easily be a derived table. And that was all based on the assumption that you need to treat consecutive hours as the same shift in a logical day.

Comment: @shawnt00 again, thanks. Even with the limitations of the interface I'm being provided this is easily close enough I can do the rest of the report in Excel.

Comment: Just to be sure, is this a suitable replacement for the above WITH?       AND (   DATEPART(hour, DATEADD(hour,  -8, ClientVisit.timein)) BETWEEN 12 AND 23

Comment: Yeah, sorry I got 8hr window stuck in my head somewhere.